# Android: How to store an image from camera and external storage into SQLite and also get it back again?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-camera, android-external-storage

I have been trying to figure out how to store an image or the location of an image in a SQLite database. And then also get the image from the database back, as well.

Here I have an activity that uses the camera. I've made comments in the code to explain my steps.

I just need to see how to edit onActivityResult here in my code. I commented some of my SQLite database attempt. How can I put this external storage image from the camera into my database and then also how can I get it back out from the database and display as an image again?

I have the database code in a seperate activity. I am just showing the code with the camera here and need general guidance of what I should do.

My activity:

```
package com.example.myapp.stepbystep;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class WalkPhoto extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_walk_photo);
        Button button= findViewById(R.id.button);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dispatchTakePictureIntent();
            }
        });
    }

    /*
    * SWITCH TO CAMERA APP
    * Define integer called request image capture.
    * Create an intent: Tell OS planning to open the camera. Action of image capture moves from this app to camera app
    * If not null (null = no camera app on device), then start the camera app
    */

    static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;

    private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        }
    }

    /*
    * GET IMAGE FROM CAMERA APP BACK TO MAIN APP
    * onActivityResult gets called when there is a result for the intent.
    * It checks whether the request image capture is true and then the result is okay
    * If correct, then the image is stored in the intent data
    * Stores data in bundle
    * Get image as bitmap
    * Use an image view to display it to user
     */

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
            ImageView imageview = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            imageview.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);



          // DatabaseHandler mydb = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
          // Walk walk = new Walk();
          //  walk.set_photo("data");
            //mydb.addWalk(walk);
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Walk Successfully Added.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            /*
            * STORE IMAGE TO EXTERNAL STORAGE
            * External storage is used to save the image to the device outside of your main app
            * Retrieve the directory
            * Create a new file and call it a name
            * Output stream
            * Compress the image
             */

            File storageLoc = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);

            File file = new File(storageLoc,  "myImage.jpg");

            try{
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
                imageBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);

                fos.close();

                scanFile(this, Uri.fromFile(file));

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }


    /*
    * BROADCAST TO REFRESH THE MEDIA CENTER WITH THE NEW IMAGE
    * scanFile sends the broadcast receiver to the media center.
    * It sees a new file in the system, scans the file, and list the file in the directory to the user
    * Have to create an intent, set the data, and send the broadcast
    * (Media center is only refreshed once when the device is restarted.
    * Overloads the OS if refreshed all of the time. So just check once here to see new file, scan, and list)
     */

    private static void scanFile(Context context, Uri imageUri){
        Intent scanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
        scanIntent.setData(imageUri);
        context.sendBroadcast(scanIntent);
    }

}
```

Comment: You can store your image as a byte[] to SQLite database.

Comment: @GhulamMoinulQuadir If I use byte[] like this, what do I put in the parenthesis for the image?..... public Walk(Parcel in) {
        this._photo=in.readByteArray();
    }

Answer (score 0):

It is quite likely that pictures take with the camera will be large, too large for them to be efficiently stored and more importantly with a high risk of crashes in SQLite when retrieving such images. This is due to a size limitation with a CursorWindow (1-2Mb).

If the images are up to around 100Kb then SQLite can be efficient.

As such the recommended method is to store and retrieve images that will be over 100Kb as a standard file and to then store the path in the database.

Assuming the larger images then DB wise you could :-

1. Create a subclass of the SQLiteOpenHelper e.g. **SO49827073DBHelper.java**

:-

```
public class SO49827073DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DBNAME ="walk.db";
    public static final int DBVERSION = 1;
    public static final String TB_WALK = "walk";
    public static final String COL_WALK_ID = BaseColumns._ID; // equates to _id
    public static final String COL_WALK_PHOTDESCRIPTION = "photo_dsecription";
    public static final String COL_WALK_PATH = "storeage_path";

    SQLiteDatabase mDB;

    public SO49827073DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DBNAME, null, DBVERSION);
        mDB = this.getWritableDatabase(); //<<< Force creation when first instantiated
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        //!!NOTE!! onCREATE ONLY RUNS ONCE WHEN DB IS CREATED
        String crtsql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TB_WALK + "(" +
                COL_WALK_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
                COL_WALK_PHOTDESCRIPTION + " TEXT," +
                COL_WALK_PATH + " TEXT" +
                ")";
        db.execSQL(crtsql);
        //!!NOTE!! to recreate tables delete the App's data or uninstall
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }

    public long addWalk(String description, String photo_path) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(COL_WALK_PHOTDESCRIPTION,description);
        cv.put(COL_WALK_PATH,photo_path);
        return this.getWritableDatabase().insert(TB_WALK,null,cv);
        //!!Note!! will return 1 or greater (the id) if insert was ok
    }

    public Cursor getAll() {
        return this.getWritableDatabase().query(
                TB_WALK,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null
        );
    }
}
```

- Noting that we are going instantiate an instance, add a few rows using the `addWalk` method and then get all the rows into a Cursor via the `getAll` method and then traverse the Cursor writing out to the log.

  2. So in the invoking activity you could have something along the lines of

:-

```
    SO49827073DBHelper mydb = new SO49827073DBHelper(this); //<<<< get instance of dbhelper
    mydb.addWalk("I fell into a puddle!!","photos/puddlefalling/fall001.jpg"); //<<<<Add row
    mydb.addWalk("Found a black cat in a coal cellar","photos/unusual/blackcatinacoalcellar.jpg");//<<<<Add row
    Cursor csr = mydb.getAll(); //<<<< get all rows the loop through them
    while (csr.moveToNext()) {
        Log.d("WALKINFRO",
                "Photo: " + csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(SO49827073DBHelper.COL_WALK_PHOTDESCRIPTION)) +
                        "\n\tStored: " + csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(SO49827073DBHelper.COL_WALK_PATH)) +
                        "\n\tID " + String.valueOf(csr.getLong(csr.getColumnIndex(SO49827073DBHelper.COL_WALK_ID)))
        );
    }
    csr.close();
```

- So take a photo file it, get the file name, get the description and call `addWalk` method passing both through.
- retrieval would be based upon the `getAll` (perhaps add a `getById` method)
- Sorry about the longish names they are for my convenience.